# How to randomize across categories holding the mean equal?

Tags: algorithm

I am looking for some conceptional inputs detached from any specific platform/software for the following problem:

Let R be a Nx2 matrix with the first column denoting the object ID and the second column the category (e.g. from 1 to 10).

```
    ID | Category 
    1  |    1    
    2  |    1     
    3  |    1     
    4  |    2     
    5  |    2     
    6  |    3     
    7  |    3     
    8  |    3     
    9  |    3     
    .  |    .     
    .  |    .
```

Further, assume we have a matrix C which assignes for each cateogry a number, e.g.:

```
     Category | Number
        1     | 0.5
        2     | 0.2
        3     | 0.9
        .     |  . 
        .     |  .
```

So for each object in matrix R a number can be mapped according to matrix C (e.g. for ID=1 with category=1, the number according to matrix C is 0.5).

The goal now is to create an algorithm which **randomizes the objects across a pre-specified category-range with the overall average of the column *number* (which is mapped to the corresponding category) being held constant**.

E.g. assume that the category-range is defined as 2 meaning that each object from category 1 can either stay in category 1, randomly be shifted to category 2 or even up to category 3. Similarly, an object from category 3 with a selected category range of 1 can either be moved down to category 2, stay at category 3 or move up to category 4). If an object is now shifted to another category, it gets assigned a new number according to matrix C which impacts the overall average across the column *numbers*.

However, all swaps have to be executed on a purely random basis with the additional constraint that the average across the column *number* after the randomization is equal to the one from the beginning.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what's the question? If you want to keep the average the same then just swap them 1 for 1 each time? Are you saying that after the randomization the number column will no longer have a 1 to 1 mapping with the category column?

Comment: Why are the matlab and SAS tags here if you want to be *detached from any specific platform/software*?

Comment: Yes,by swapping 1 for 1 each time, the average will be held constant. However, this poses some new challenges. E.g. how to select the counterparty for the swap? How to handle varying numbers of objects per category (e.g. imagine category 1 has 100 objects, category 2 only 10, how would the swap look like since swapping 1:1 is now strongly dependend from where you start (e.g with a simple do-loop going top-down). Further, once swapped, both objects may not swapped again since this could harm the constraint of the maximum category-range allowance. I am just looking for an easy way to handle this

Comment: I don't see how swapping anything would change the overall average. If you have a finite sequence of numbers, the average is the same for any permutation (ie, sum is commutative)!

Comment: @BruoReis. I have updated my question, I hope this clarifies your concern.